# Reusing DAOs in another web application

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc, persistence

I coded a website using Spring MVC and I now want to code its back end (i.e. dashboard or CMS) in order for the administrators to manage it.

Since I coded all the DAOs for the front end, I would like to reuse them for the back end (since the DB tables are obviously the same, front and back end share the same persistence context).

My idea was to code the back end as a new web application, where the DAOs and domain objects were exported from the front end as a jar file and imported in the back end project. The persistence is managed by JPA and Hibernate and every DAO class looks like this:

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {
    private EntityManager em;

    // ... Methods...

    @PersistenceContext
    void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
}
```

The persistence configuration (i.e. JPA + Hibernate + MySQL) of the back end website is exactly the same as the one for the front end. I was expecting this configuration to be injected in the DAOs that are being imported in the JAR file but this is obviously not happening. Everytime I try to use any of the methods in any of the DAOs I get an exception similar to:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserJpa is not mapped [SELECT u FROM UserJpa u WHERE u.alias = :alias AND u.closed = false]

Is there a solution to solve this problem? Or is there a better approach to what I want to achieve (i.e. code the back end using the same front end DAOs)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering why you can't deploy both UIs as a single application, with role based access for users and admins.  Since you're already using Spring, Spring Security would be a natural choice here to restrict access to admin pages by role.  Why rewrite the back end?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @duffymo. Well said, I initially started doing like that. I'm already using Spring Security for the front end since most of the website is only for registered users. But then I didn't know how to properly configure Spring Security. For example, if I'm not logged in, example.com/dashboard/manage-users should redirect to example.com/dashboard/login. While example.com/my-profile should redirect to example.com/login (or example.com/registration). How can I do this..? Thanks!

Comment: @satoshi, that's a really good question.  I think you should post that as a separate question.  You'll get better answers and it'll help other people who have similar issues find it easier! (Like me, I'd be very interested in that answer ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

U need export the entity classes too because hibernate need load all entities to work with database or exclude the entities in the new config file

about Spring Security i recommend use unique login page, but different home page, i think you can set different home page by rol

Answer (score 0):

> UserJpa is not mapped [SELECT u FROM UserJpa u WHERE u.alias = :alias AND u.closed = false]

It sounds like you've simply forgotten to include the mapping configuration from the first application in the second one. Make sure that the JPA runtime in the second application has all the same configuration regarding `UserJpa` class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing OR mapping using Hibernate annotations or an XML configuration? In the former case, the packagesToScan property on your Hibernate SessionFactory isn't seeing the UserJpa class, possibly because you're not loading the JAR you think you're loading. In the latter case, you're missing an import of hibernate.cfg.xml or its equivalent.